# New tag for Lightning Console App

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

I couldn't find a tag for questions on **Lightning Console Apps**.

Is it possible to create a new tag for the same or is it because it's still in Beta version that the tag is not present in SFSE?

Comment: Is that really a distinct tag from [`[lightning-apps]`](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/lightning-apps/info)?

Comment: No, I don't think that it's very distinct from lightning-apps (you're absolutely right ), but I think that it is very different from a standard navigation; so thought would be better if users could differentiate between them in some way, here in SFSE, since the console apps have unique features (like split view) which the apps in standard navigation doesn't have.